# Let X and Z form a random sample from a poisson dist.If Y=min( X,Z), what is P(Y=1)??

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let X and Z form a random sample of poisson distribution and define Y=min( X and Z)

What is P(Y=1)??

I think Y is minimum of two.

If X=1, then Z can be any number except 0

If Z=1, then X can be any number except 0

I think answer should be P(X=1) x (1-P(Z=0)) and multiplying it by two would be probability that Y=1

However, the answer is wrong...

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the rate parameter of the Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X, Z \sim \text{Pos}(\lambda)$. The event $\min (X, Z) = 1$ is the same as the event $X = 1, Z \neq 0$ or $Z = 1, X \neq 0$. As you stated, the two events have the same probability, but only when considered independently of one another. It is possible that $X = Z = 1$ and both events be satisfied. Using

> $$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B),$$

we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y = 1) &= \mathbb{P}(X = 1 \cap Z \neq 0) + \mathbb{P}(Z = 1 \cap X \neq 0) - \mathbb{P}(X = 1 \cap Z = 1) \\
&= 2\mathbb{P}(X = 1 \cap Z \neq 0) - \mathbb{P}(X = 1 \cap Z = 1) \\
&= 2\mathbb{P}(X = 1)(1 - \mathbb{P}(Z = 0)) - \mathbb{P}(X = 1)\mathbb{P}(Z = 1) \\
&= 2(e^{-\lambda}\lambda)(1 - e^{-\lambda}) - e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^2
\end{align*}

Substitute the appropriate value of $\lambda$ and simplify. Alternatively you could compute the probability of $X = 1, Z \neq 0$ and $Z = 1, X > 1$ and add. In these types of problems you should be careful in defining what events are equivalent to the event you are given. The inclusion-exclusion principle is a simple and often overlooked technique in these types of problems.